# Link redirection with ID not working properly in mozilla,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, mozilla

I am having a hectic problem with one of my website while working in mozilla, the problem may seems small but it ruins my time, hope anyone can help me.

I have a static website, there I used anchor link to link this site with another webpage. While clicking on a particular link the page redirects to another page in the same website. But I need to land it in different positions, So I used anchor links to redirect.

I am attaching my redirection code here.

```
<a href="content/index.php#auto-vid" class="maroon">
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <p>content</p>



    <div class="arrow-outer">
         <span class="read_more">Read More </span> <span class="arrow arrow-right"></span>
    </div>
    </a>
```

This work cool in chrome and IE, but not in mozilla, while I click the read more button, next page will appear. But

> it won't go to the particular ID, Instead keep remaining on top of the
>   page.

I tried to debug it, There I could see some errors, like this,

> Empty string passed to getElementById(). in jquery file.

but when i reload the same page this error disappears and the page will load correctly and redirected to the correspondent ID, But if i copy the link and paste it in another tab, it won't work. Why is it so, Is there any one who can help me. I am attaching you my [website link](http://redeemergroup.com/), please check it mozilla, Thank you.